# Django and Bootstrap: offline reload page issue (netdna.bootstrapcdn.com)

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap-3, offlineapps

I have a Django Project that **works**. I have "bootstrapped" it a bit using in my *base_html*:

```
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}
{# Display django.contrib.messages as Bootstrap alerts #}
{% bootstrap_messages %}
```

in **settings.py**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'bootstrap_toolkit',
    'bootstrap3',
    'django_admin_bootstrapped.bootstrap3',
    'django_admin_bootstrapped',             
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'jquery',
    'jquery_ui',
    'homepage',
    'simpleapp',
)
```

Perfect, if I surf between pages using my buttons&co. it appears bootstrapped and all is ok!

**BUT...**

I noticed that if my pc is offline, (only) when I *reload* the page (or I use in some js *parent.window.location.reload(true);*), it appears *not* bootstrapped! Moreover I noticed that when I'm online and I reload the page, the browser searches for *netdna.bootstrapcdn.com...* but this is not my goal: I have to create a project that works **offline**.

How can I resolve the reload problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default settings of `django-bootstrap3` point to CDNs as [documented](http://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html):

```
# Default settings
BOOTSTRAP3 = {

    # The URL to the jQuery JavaScript file
    'jquery_url': '//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js',

    # The Bootstrap base URL
    'base_url': '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/',
    ...
```

You should store the related files in your `static` directory and set the `jquery_url` and `base_url` settings of `bootstrap3`. For example:

```
BOOTSTRAP3 = {

    # The URL to the jQuery JavaScript file
    'jquery_url': '/static/js/jquery.min.js',

    # The Bootstrap base URL
    'base_url': '/static/css/',

    # The complete URL to the Bootstrap CSS file (None means derive it from base_url)
    'css_url': '/static/css/bootstrap.min.css',

    # The complete URL to the Bootstrap CSS file (None means no theme)
    'theme_url': '/static/css/bootstrap.theme.min.css',

    # The complete URL to the Bootstrap JavaScript file (None means derive it from base_url)
    'javascript_url': '/static/js/bootstrap.min.js',
```

An alternative way would be to hard-code the `css` and `js` locations into your templates, like:

```
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.theme.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have cache enabled on your browser, it will not store the CSS and JS downloaded from the CDN. To avoid this, either

1. Enable caching in your browser
2. Download the minified bootstrap css and js and place them in your project's static directory. Then link to them like `<script src="{% static "bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>`. If you go this route, don't forget to publish your static files.

Comment: You should probably use the Bootstrap 3 app's settings in order to point it to the proper JS and CSS locations, to avoid having bootstrap loaded twice (once from the CDN, and once locally). Also, enabling caching isn't exactly the right way to make a website function offline.

Comment: If your assets are hosted on a CDN, and you don't cache them, you can't have them offline unless you have them available locally. Could easily define something in `settings.py` like `OFFLINE_DEV = True` to choose to load the local versions only when offline.

Comment: Indeed, you can't have them offline locally when you develop if they're not cached. However, even if you cache them, you won't have them offline if you force-refresh and bust the cache (which e.g. Chrome will do if you reload). Caching just isn't the proper way to have offline access. Hosting local versions is (to your credit, that was your second suggestion).